# 2 TreePanels with same store?

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, ext.net

I have the following **Case**:

TreePanel (width: 400, Height: 300) with a button in the TopBar. When user click on this Button , we open a new Window (width: 800, Height: 600) containing the same TreePanel.

My **Question** is:

Is it possible to copy the TreePanel into the new Window or at least using the TreePanel's store as a store for the new TreePanel?
Or I am obliged to create a new TreePanel with a new Store?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same store in both TreePanels. Give the store a `storeId`, and then user the `Ext.data.StoreManager` to get the store based on the `storeId`.

For more information: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager

As for using the same TreePanel, you can't use the exact same instance, but you can create a class that extends TreePanel, and then just instantiate your custom TreePanel in both the places you want it.

Comment: Yes Ext.data.StoreManager works in ExtJS , thanks forgivenson, and in Ext.Net i just noticed "thank to you" that there is a StoreID property which do what i want.